# New sink drain not aligned with trap

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, sink, p-trap

Just had a new sink installed in my bathroom and the drain hole on this new sink is centered compared to my old sink which was off center and further back. When I look underneath the sink the P trap is now sitting about 5" farther back and slightly to the left side from where the sink hole is now.

Is this an easy fix that I can do myself with just new parts or is it more complicated that will require a professional? Do I need some sort of extension or new P trap? Can I turn the pipe counterclockwise to try to get it closer to the sink drain and then add attachment?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Traps are easy and parts are readily available. You can configure it in many positions to suit your space and arrangement (maximizing usable cabinet space). One caveat is to avoid creating an S-trap.

Comment: What would be considered a S trap? Can show diagran?

Comment: Please refer to your nearest search engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to turn the clamp nut by the wall...

[image]

...which will allow the horizontal portion of the drain connection to pull out of the wall. It may have enough slide connection so it can be reclamped to use the existing pipe to reach the new down spout on the sink.

If it is not long enough then you will need to purchase new parts to achieve a longer horizontal portion. Do take the old pipe with you to the store so you can see what type and size of parts to place in your shopping basket.

Note that it is quite common to use a combination of the back wall slide connection and the rotation of the P-trap joint to achieve getting the pipes perfectly aligned with the sink drain. The following picture is an attempt to show how this adjustment works. There are only really two positions where there will be perfect alignment when the horizontal positioning from the wall causes the sink drain center to intersect with the arc of swing of the P-trap.

[image]

Note that if the center of the drain hole is farther from the center line of the wall pipe than the radius of the P-trap arc then there is no position where you can get things to line up. In that case then you need to use additional fittings to angle from the wall connection more toward the new drain location.

Comment: So you are saying that by opening the clamp by the wall there might be more of extension inside which I can pull out to reach the new drain and then once achieved I can reclamp it? Should I also open that second clamp on the front and rotate the vertical portion counterclockwise to align with sink since right now it is positioned to the left? Do you think there is extra tubing in the wall to extend or will I need to get a longer extension? If I get new extension I will need to cut it to length correct since there is no adjustable type?

Comment: @JoeyDYI - Yes I am saying that there may be some slide length available in the existing horizontal part. Only checking on your end will determine if this is the case.  You will for sure need to adjust the rotation of the P-trap. As I said it usually takes a combination of the horizontal length and rotation of the P-trap to get the thing lined up with the sink drain. A longer horizontal extension will likely require cutting to length if there is limited slide in adjustment at the back wall. Cutting can easily be done with a hack saw or other fine toothed saw.

Comment: So if there is not enough extension the I should get the longer horizontal extension and should get a new P trap while at it so both parts are new. So connection of the horizontal to wall extension is done by using clamps and the p trap to horizontal also by clamps. No need for any type of plumbers putty or glue correct?

Comment: The connections of the plastic pipes on sink drains use compression type seals that the are pressed tight around the pipe in the joints by the clamping nut. These are often supplied as a nylon part that is clear or whitish in color. I recommend that you look to see if your store has these seals in a colored style of much more rubbery type of plastic  as they seal much much better than the standard nylon types. The two parts of the P-trap that join the two curved parts together are generally designed to seal together via a taper fit connection with each other that is the tightened  (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) using a clamp ring nut similar to the slide connections with the aforementioned seals. You will also most likely going to be using a slide type connection on the sink drain down pipe where it mates with the P-trap. Plumbers putty and glue are generally not used on these sink drain parts themselves. You will most likely be using plumbers putty when you install the sink drain assembly into the hole in the bottom of the sink.

Comment: @joeydiy, you should recognize Michael’s assistance with up votes and acceptance of his answer, you might get another long winded answer but what Michael has provided is all you need and this will help others find a good answer.+ it was also a good question with a photo, keep them coming +

Comment: If the extension is not enough and I have to get a new one then couldn't I just slide it into the wall portion to length I need and attach the p trap to it without cutting it since that is what I will be doing first with the setup I have here? Is there a certain amount of the tube that should only go into the wall portion?

Comment: @JoeyDYI - There will be a limit of how much the pipe can slide into the wall. I've already told you that you have to check your setup to see of the pipe does actually slide into the wall some. If it does not then you will have to very carefully work out the correct length of the new part to get the alignment to work.

Comment: OK so opened the clamp on the wall side extension and pulled out as much as I could on the extension to see if it would reach. Rotated the P trap part angle as well. The extension did not quite reach to the point where the p trap will be directly underneath the sink hole.  The wall extension was almost to the edge since I could feel the pipe no longer sitting steady on the wall part and was almost to the edge and bending down.  So I assume that enough was into the wall part to keep it stable and straight. This means I need to buy a new extension and cut it. Any good way to measure correctly?

Comment: @JoeyDYI - One good way is to try out the fit with uncut parts. If too long cut off a bit and then try fit again. Iterate till you get it. You may want to investigate the wall piping some. It probably goes back into a TEE or ELBOW in the wall. If so you do not want to push in the horizontal piece all the way in so that the end hits the back inside of the wall pipe. If that was done it would restrict drain water and lead to a clogged drain. So make sure to hold back a good 2.5 inches or so. You can easily insert a tape measure to find out how far in the wall pipe goes before it turns vertical.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I was able to cut the extension to size and made the connections to p trap and installed my faucet. All went well and so far no issues. Now to tackle the kitchen sink which was installed as well, but need to hook up the plumbing as well. Will probably start a new a thread to get help on it too.